# Can a SCTP entity still send data once it has received a SHUTDOWN chunk?

Tags: sctp

i'm learning SCTP protocols and I cannot figure out that one thing.

Once the server has received a SHUTDOWN message from the client, is it allowed to send data back?
And what about the ACK messages, can they still be sent/received or must the server immediately respond with a SHUTDOWN ACK?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHUTDOWN chunk is just an indication that remote side would like to close the association. The local side still can transmit data it has previously received from upper layer. As the matter of fact the local side have to deliver everything that has been received from upper layer and has not been delivered yet to remote end.

According to RFC [4960, chapter 9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#section-9.2):

> Upon reception of the SHUTDOWN, the peer endpoint shall

- enter the SHUTDOWN-RECEIVED state,
- stop accepting new data from its SCTP user, and
- verify, by checking the Cumulative TSN Ack field of the chunk,
  that all its outstanding DATA chunks have been received by the
  SHUTDOWN sender.

...

> If there are still outstanding DATA chunks left, the SHUTDOWN
> receiver MUST continue to follow normal data transmission procedures
> defined in Section 6, until all outstanding DATA chunks are
> acknowledged; however, the SHUTDOWN receiver MUST NOT accept new data
> from its SCTP user.

Once all outgoing data has been successfully delivered to remote end, it is allowed to send SHUTDOWN_ACK:

> If the receiver of the SHUTDOWN has no more outstanding DATA chunks,
> the SHUTDOWN receiver MUST send a SHUTDOWN ACK and start a T2-
> shutdown timer of its own, entering the SHUTDOWN-ACK-SENT state.  If
> the timer expires, the endpoint must resend the SHUTDOWN ACK.

The same applies to SACK chunks. Local side still can receive SACKs confirming outstanding data. Local side however should not send any new SACK chunk to remote end, because the SHUTDOWN chunk is send only after remote end successfully delivered all of it outgoing data.

Hopefully that helps.